# How has geometry been applied in cognitive science?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, mathematical-psychology

What areas of geometry are used in psychology/cognitive science/neuroscience? Are the applications of a sophisticated nature or superficial?

Comment: Do you mean employed in the study of? If you could just make sense of that line ty and welcome :)

Comment: Yes. 'Employed' in the study of.

Comment: Do you consider general applications of linear algebra as geometry? Or must some specific geometric insights beyond that be used?

Comment: Do you count topics like the psychology of visual perception and gestalt psychology, or do you mean only areas where geometry is used to study a cognitive process which is not directly related to geometry itself? Because the first would be a very wide area, while the second interpretation will give you a more interesting list.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few off the top of my head from neuroscience:

- neural activity may primarily exist on low dimensional [attractors](http://www.nature.com/neuro/journal/v16/n8/full/nn.3450.html).
- reconstructing PET signal origins from emitted gamma rays
- It's widely believed our brains are gyrencephalic (wrinkly) to maximize surface area.
- Various distance metrics (Euclidean, Mahalanobis) are common tools for clustering data, for example [spike sorting](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Spike_sorting).
- Neuron morphology (shape) follows function.
- Microgeometry of objects is important for tactile texture perception.
- Bat echolocation and fish electrosensation are limited in range due to the inverse square law.

Answer (score 3):

Semantic foraging in memory is another nice example: concepts in memory can be represented spatially as locations in multidimensional space, and the route we travel in that 'space' has a lot in common with the optimal foraging movements animals adopt.

http://www.indiana.edu/~clcl/Papers/HTJ_Foraging.pdf

Comment: I was reading [Goldstone and Son's chapter on 'similarity' in the Cambridge Handbook of Thinking and Reasoning](http://cognitrn.psych.indiana.edu/rgoldsto/pdfs/similarity2004.pdf) the other day, where they discuss the geometric multidimensional scaling approach to similarity.

In a nutshell (the chapter describes it in detail), the theory holds that if you represent the values of relevant features of anything as independent dimensions, concepts can be located in high-dimensional space, and distances/relationships between them calculated geometrically.

Answer (score 1):

Though not a direct bridge between Linguistics and Cognitive Science, [***Semasiographic***](http://languagesindanger.eu/book-of-knowledge/writing/) communication systems are a ripe territory for the studio of [Mereology](http://philpapers.org/browse/mereology).

---

Off-hand, consider:

Dewalque, A. [*Brentano and the parts of the mental: a mereological approach to phenomenal intentionality.*](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11097-012-9293-8#page-1) **Phenomenology and the Cognitive Sciences**, September 2013, Volume 12, Issue 3, pp 447-464

Comment: Fascinating answers! I'd love to see a little elaboration here though, as I don't think the hyperlinked GRE-level vocab words are doing justice to your ideas, which come very unexpectedly and usefully from outside the proverbial box.

Answer (score -1):

The book Theories of Meaningfulness of [Louis Narens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Narens) deals with Erlanger program, which is the connection between group theory and projective geometry.